# How to check for Empty data Condition in spark Dataset in JAVA

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset, apache-spark-sql

I've been trying to do a check for result dataset in spark of whether it is empty or has data. I did below following things.

```
dataset.rdd().isEmpty();
```

2.

```
try{
           dataset.head(1)
         }catch(Exception e){
          status ="No data";
          }
```

3.

```
try{
         dataset.first();
          }catch(Exception e){  
           status ="No data";
          }
```

4.

```
dataset.limit(1).count()>0;
```

All this are taking a lot of time to complete when comparatively huge data is present. I need to get a efficient solution for this.

Comment: Yeah . @philantrovert but That's what I have said in the Question description. That I have tried all those?? But evrything is taking a lot of time. when dataset is not empty.

Comment: These are the options you get. If `dataset` has complex wide dependencies, then taking even a single element will be expensive.